# WooCommerce product sorting VERY slow

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, sort

I have 2800 products in my WooCommerce store. Trying to use the All Products > "Sorting" utility in the backend to edit the desired order for them to appear is excruciatingly slow. Even if I filter into a category with ~200 products, it's quite slow to save each product. The process of updating the database with a sort value after EVERY drag reorder seems like overkill.

Is there anyway to drag them into my desired order (not have it automatically trigger Ajax) and once I'm one manually trigger the order of them to appear?

Comment: Not sure what the difficulty is, but you might want to look at a function that would directly manipulate the database - updating the order field - instead of working from the product edit screen.

Comment: I ended up getting Advanced Post Types Order plugin as quick fix, still would be nice if Woo would work better.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plugin that deals with this fairly effectively.

https://github.com/haydenw/woocommerce-product-sorting

Comment: This plugin increased sort time on a site with 20,000+ products from minutes per sort to ~3 seconds per sort.